# Fast pandas Timeseries event based time range calculations

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time-series

I have a timeseries (freq = 'D') of events which takes the value 0 if there is no event and 1 if there is an event. Typically this tends to occur over a continuous range of days.

I would like to calculate two variables within the event time range:

1. A value that represents the week number since the event started (with Saturday of the week being the end of week).
2. The day numbering within the week since the event started

Here is an example of what I am trying to do

```
# Dummy up a test frame
date = pd.date_range(start='20150101', end='20150121', freq='D')
event = np.zeros(len(date))
event[2:5] = 1.
event[15:20] = 1.
df_test = pd.DataFrame({'date': date, 'event': event})
```

The data looks like this. As you can see, the event occurs twice in the time range. I have calculated the 'snapped_date' so that it refers to the Saturday of the week.

```
In[2]: df_test
Out[2]: 
         date  event
0  2015-01-01    0.0
1  2015-01-02    0.0
2  2015-01-03    1.0
3  2015-01-04    1.0
4  2015-01-05    1.0
5  2015-01-06    0.0
6  2015-01-07    0.0
7  2015-01-08    0.0
8  2015-01-09    0.0
9  2015-01-10    0.0
10 2015-01-11    0.0
11 2015-01-12    0.0
12 2015-01-13    0.0
13 2015-01-14    0.0
14 2015-01-15    0.0
15 2015-01-16    1.0
16 2015-01-17    1.0
17 2015-01-18    1.0
18 2015-01-19    1.0
19 2015-01-20    1.0
20 2015-01-21    0.0
```

I started off by computing the week bound for each date like this:

```
df_test.loc[:, 'snapped_date'] = df_test.date.map(pd.tseries.frequencies.to_offset('W-SAT').rollforward)
```

Now, I would like to compute the two new columns below:

```
         date snapped_date  event  week_of_event  day_within_week_of_event
0  2015-01-01   2015-01-03    0.0            0.0                       0.0
1  2015-01-02   2015-01-03    0.0            0.0                       0.0
2  2015-01-03   2015-01-03    1.0            1.0                       1.0
3  2015-01-04   2015-01-10    1.0            2.0                       1.0
4  2015-01-05   2015-01-10    1.0            2.0                       2.0
5  2015-01-06   2015-01-10    0.0            0.0                       0.0
6  2015-01-07   2015-01-10    0.0            0.0                       0.0
7  2015-01-08   2015-01-10    0.0            0.0                       0.0
8  2015-01-09   2015-01-10    0.0            0.0                       0.0
9  2015-01-10   2015-01-10    0.0            0.0                       0.0
10 2015-01-11   2015-01-17    0.0            0.0                       0.0
11 2015-01-12   2015-01-17    0.0            0.0                       0.0
12 2015-01-13   2015-01-17    0.0            0.0                       0.0
13 2015-01-14   2015-01-17    0.0            0.0                       0.0
14 2015-01-15   2015-01-17    0.0            0.0                       0.0
15 2015-01-16   2015-01-17    1.0            1.0                       1.0
16 2015-01-17   2015-01-17    1.0            1.0                       2.0
17 2015-01-18   2015-01-24    1.0            2.0                       1.0
18 2015-01-19   2015-01-24    1.0            2.0                       2.0
19 2015-01-20   2015-01-24    1.0            2.0                       3.0
20 2015-01-21   2015-01-24    0.0            0.0                       0.0
```

Is there any time series functionality in pandas that can help me do this in a fast and Pythonic way? I have multiple tseries like this and wanted to eventually like to do a grouped transform.

Answer (score 1):

With this ugly solution , can achieve this ....

```
df['new']=((df.date.dt.dayofweek+1)//7).cumsum()      
df['new2']=df.event.diff().ne(0).cumsum()    
df['week_of_event']=df.loc[df.event!=0].groupby('new2').new.apply(lambda x : x.rolling(len(x), min_periods=1).apply(lambda y: len(np.unique(y))))
df['day_within_week_of_event']=df.loc[df.event!=0].groupby(['new2','week_of_event']).cumcount()+1


df.fillna(0)
Out[140]: 
         date  event  new  new2  week_of_event  day_within_week_of_event
0  2015-01-01    0.0    0     1            0.0                       0.0
1  2015-01-02    0.0    0     1            0.0                       0.0
2  2015-01-03    1.0    0     2            1.0                       1.0
3  2015-01-04    1.0    1     2            2.0                       1.0
4  2015-01-05    1.0    1     2            2.0                       2.0
5  2015-01-06    0.0    1     3            0.0                       0.0
6  2015-01-07    0.0    1     3            0.0                       0.0
7  2015-01-08    0.0    1     3            0.0                       0.0
8  2015-01-09    0.0    1     3            0.0                       0.0
9  2015-01-10    0.0    1     3            0.0                       0.0
10 2015-01-11    0.0    2     3            0.0                       0.0
11 2015-01-12    0.0    2     3            0.0                       0.0
12 2015-01-13    0.0    2     3            0.0                       0.0
13 2015-01-14    0.0    2     3            0.0                       0.0
14 2015-01-15    0.0    2     3            0.0                       0.0
15 2015-01-16    1.0    2     4            1.0                       1.0
16 2015-01-17    1.0    2     4            1.0                       2.0
17 2015-01-18    1.0    3     4            2.0                       1.0
18 2015-01-19    1.0    3     4            2.0                       2.0
19 2015-01-20    1.0    3     4            2.0                       3.0
20 2015-01-21    0.0    3     5            0.0                       0.0
```